# How to share code between some of the subclasses?

Tags: java, oop, access-modifiers

I have an abstract class with multiple sub-classes (more than 20 as of now) and there is a code and variables that I like to share only between 2 of the Sub-classes.

If I will put the methods and the variables in the Super-class then all of the Sub-classes will have access to them, but I want that only 2 of the Sub-classes will have an access to them and basically will know they exist.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps these 2 sub-classes should extend an intermediate abstract class that extends your base class.

Comment: The classes hierarchy in Java isn't limited to 2 levels :)

Comment: Could you explain what the difference between the 2 classes and the rest is? Because most people are suggesting multiple levels of classes, while your problem might be more easily resolved with an interface (apart from the abstract class).

Comment: Most probably you do not need `inheritance`, but you need `composition` instead

Comment: Classes are not really intended to share data between code, but to model common behavior. Saying you have "20 subclasses" sounds to me like a code smell.

Comment: Hi @shay n. If my or any other answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course, there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it by applying the [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle: create a new class that contains the functionality which should be shared between the 2 subclasses and use a reference to an instance of the new class inside of the 2 subclasses.

This way you will avoid having to add an additional layer in between the subclasses and the super class and your code will be more flexible and easier to maintain.

This approach is advisable almost always when it doesn't feel natural to add some shared functionality to a super-class and obtain it via inheritance. When in doubt, always ask yourself whether a **HAS-A relationship** (composition) feels more appropriate than an **IS-A relationship** (inheritance).

Although grouping together several functionalities in one super-class can be helpful, if you need to share a single functionality between several classes, probably it will be more appropriate to implement it by using composition.

Answer (score 2):

*All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection.* (by [David Wheeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection))

Thus simply create another (abstract) class that extends your base class and that adds those common things that you only need in those specific child classes.

The above quote isn't always true, but at least *conceptually*, another **helpful** abstraction is most often the best way out of a design problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner Made a bit more clear that this is a bit of an ironic quote.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an actual example, so you can see how this problem should be tackled.

We have a class called `Alive`. We will use this as the parent class of `Dog`, `Wolf` and `Human`. Where we need `Dog` and `Wolf` to have a method `growl()`, but `Human` doesn't.

```
class Alive{

    abstract void smell(){};
    abstract void see(){};
    abstract void hear(){};
 }

class Canis extends Alive{

    abstract void growl(){};
 }

class Human extends Alive{
}

class Dog extends Canis{
}

class Wolf extends Canis{
}
```

This is a diagram of what the inheritance hierarchy looks like:

```
                             Alive  
                             /  \
                            /    \
                           /      \
                        Human    Canis
                                  / \
                                 /   \
                               Dog   Wolf
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to inheritance you can use composition. Create an other class and put your methods and variables in it and make a reference to this new class in your 2 classes. Also using correct packaging and access modifiers you are capable of accessing your new class only from those 2 client classes.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend abstract class from the base class, put the methods you want to be shared in this class, and then extend the two classes you want to share methods from the new middleware class.